# Prestashop 1.6 Controller override

Tags: php, prestashop

I know how to override things in Prestashop. I'm trying to override Category Controller to display custom categories (different template with different data).

I copied CategoryController to /modules/mymodule/override/controllers/front and I have module controller at /modules/mymodule/controllers/front/display.php and there's initContent method.

How can I use modified CategoryController in my display.php controller?

Answer (score 0):

You have created two different controllers:

1. Overriden CategoryController
2. ModuleController

Using 1. within 2. is nonesense - which means that you do something semantically wrong. If you want to to display custom categories with different template you need only to override the CategoryController, and set the proper template (if you will use two different templates for displaying categories). If you need only one template, just override the controller and change the theme template.

Comment: So, how to use overridden CategoryController in module? I'd like to get result of CategoryController::initContent() on http://domain.com/module/mymodule/category

Comment: I mean... I copy original CategoryController to mymodule/controllers/front/category.php, I make my changes in category.php. As a result I can access /module/mymodule/category?id_category=1 and see default category tpl with data from my modified category controller (category.php). Is it possible? Category.php will be modified to get products from some API. Templete won't change and the module will be template-independent.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just do not forget to name the class properly and to extend ModuleFrontController.